# Using CSV data to calculate while using the column names in a formula string

Tags: r

The entire code below is trying to calculate data in csv using an expression. But the csv columns are not recognized even though I used `row.names=1` and `as.formula(expr)`.

```
expr <- "(((Blue_482/Green_557)/(RedEdge_717/Blue_482)) *((NIR_831/RedEdge_717)/(Green_557/Red_667)))"

csv <- read.csv(file=input_csv, header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=1)
pre <- as.formula(expr)
#with(data, glm(as.formula(expr)) )
fit <- rpart(lm(pre), method="class",data=csv)
```

My data is the following.

```
    SPM,Blue_482,Green_557,Red_667,RedEdge_717,NIR_831
    36,0.010417017,0.01488165,0.014811581,0.012048874,0.005534498
    36,0.009935392,0.014388976,0.014254432,0.011446002,0.005325746
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]) : 
object 'Blue_482' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the `csv` object variable name should be in front of every column. Thus, the code below works.

```
expr <- "(((csv$Blue_482/csv$Green_557)/(csv$RedEdge_717/csv$Blue_482)) *((csv$NIR_831/csv$RedEdge_717)/(csv$Green_557/csv$Red_667)))"
csv <- read.csv(file=input_csv, header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=NULL)
calculated <- (eval(parse(text = expr)))
```